# problem with presentModalViewController and uiwebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm using presentModalViewController for my "info" view.
I've added an infobutton ah the top of my NavigationController and, when it is pressed, i call this method

```
about *ab = [[about alloc] initWithNibName:@"about" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ab.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; 
[self presentModalViewController: ab animated: YES];
[ab release];
```

in my info page there is an UIWebView, that contains some links.
Using this (and setting the uiwebview delegate as self)

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

if an user touch a link, that link is open with safari.

What's the problem? 
that if you do that, and you return into the app, you are not in the info-view, but in the main-view... and (this is the problem) if you touch the infobutton, nothing happened! You can't open the info-view again!

Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `[ab release]`. Does that work?

Comment: The other buttons, do they still work after closing the app. (btw. your iPhone does supports multitasking right, just for sure...). Does it work when you run it in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of displaying the info view controller as a modal, just push it onto the navigation controller's stack?  Should have a similar effect, but then you *should* still be on the info screen when you return to the app.  Something like this instead of the `presentModalViewController:animated:` call:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: ab animated: YES];
```

Comment: is, i know... but i want the `presentModalView` effect... :)